# How can I set the text with the result of a query?

Tags: java, android, sql

**I have this app that has a list of chips and respectives rows, I want to be able to show the information in the textviews of the chip that appears. Note that the chips are already in the database**

**Creating table**

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ Table2 +" ("+
                TABLE_ID_CHIPS +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                numero_chip +" TEXT, "+ Marca_Exploracao +" TEXT, "+Marca_Auricular +" TEXT, "+Data_Nascimento +" TEXT, "+NIF +" TEXT)" );
    }
```

**Method that gets all the chips**

```
 public Cursor getChips(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from chips where chip_number= 2" , new String[]{});
        return c;
    }
```

**Method that shows the information of chip number 2(In the query above) anda sets the text of the respective textviews**

public void MostrarChips(){

```
bd = new BaseDados(this);
Cursor c = bd.getChips();
item = new ArrayList<String>();


if(c.moveToFirst()){

    do{
        **//I have some doubts here**
        marcaexploracao.setText(c.getString(1).toString());
        marcaauricular.setText(c.getString(2).toString());
        datanascimento.setText(c.getString(3).toString());
        nif.setText(c.getString(4).toString());

    }while(c.moveToNext());

}

}
```

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? What isn't 'working?

Comment: My problem is that the text that shows in the textviews is like "android.support.textview......" it doesnt show the information of the chip :/

Comment: Why you are returning Cursor object from getChips() method. Just make an ArrayLisr inside getChips initialize it and return.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedbak. BlackHatSamurai find the solution. Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do something like this:

```
c.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("yourColumnNameHere"))
```

So if your column name is `chips` you'd do:

```
 c.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("chips"))
```

Comment: Thanks!! You help me a lot. You are the best.

Comment: Well you can give me one, and you can accept the answer as well @Jose. Regardless, I'm glad that I was able to help you out :)

Comment: Can you help me with other thing?

Comment: @Jose what is the other thing? What ever it is I'd suggest you create a new question for it.